# Angular number filter in HTML not working; empty string is returned

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have an array returning number of places.

```
      <h3 ng-controller="TotalPlacesCtrl">Total Places: {{places.places}}</h3>
```

Whenever I add `{{places.places | number}}`
The page shows no results.
Also if I remove `| number` It displays number as [1292] But I want it to display in 1,292 format.
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it displays as `[1292]`, that means that `places.places` is not a number. It's an array containing a single element. So you need `places.places[0]`.

Comment: How do I add that in my angular. I have $scope.places = data; do I just add places.places[0] after that

Comment: No. In your view, instead of using `places.places` like you're doing to access the number, you need to use `places.places[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
{{places.places[0] | number}}
```

Seems to me that is an array and you are refrencing the whole array instead do refer with its index.